# Make password textbox value visible after each character input javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript

I have tried below plugin to make password textbox value visible after each character input
https://github.com/better-owlet/jquery-mobilePassword/blob/master/js/jquery.mobilePassword.js is not working properly(characters are overlapping) when we type fast. any one has solution for the same.

plugin using below:

[https://github.com/better-owlet/jquery-mobilePassword/blob/master/js/…](https://github.com/better-owlet/jquery-mobilePassword/blob/master/js/%E2%80%A6)

in JSP I am calling method

```
$("input[type=password]").mobilePassword(); 
<input name="password" type="password" class ="input" size="10">`
```

Comment: Hey welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide some of your code to show an attempt and give a more detailed description of what your problem is!

Comment: plugin using below: https://github.com/better-owlet/jquery-mobilePassword/blob/master/js/jquery.mobilePassword.js   in JSP I am calling method  $("input[type=password]").mobilePassword(); <input name="password" type="password" class ="input" size="10">